# Unable to merge dex using LiveParse Query

Tags: android, gradle, dex

I am working on LiveQueryParse, but when I am using both gradle links, it is giving me error below:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

I am using these gradle links and it is giving me an error:

```
compile 'com.github.tgio:parse-livequery:1.0.3'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.16.3'
```

I have already put in my app Gradle file following codes:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dcas.user"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.tgio:parse-livequery:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.16.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
}
```

I have also cleaned my project already, deleted build files and also .gradle folder as well, but still I am getting the error. I have already searched similar question and solution, but still it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should use **`implementation`** instead of **`compile`**.
- set all updated version.

You should set

```
compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "//"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 27
```

Then use

```
implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.17.3'
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: @UKhan Happy coding. Move ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Your *compile SDK version* **MUST** match the *support library*:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Also i update your dependencies like below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.tgio:parse-livequery:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.17.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
}
```

I hope this should help you